# I have a sodium silicate sealant in my car and need to find a way to soften it

Tags: solutions, solubility

Poured Blue devil sealant and found that it clogged my engine. Can someone who knows about chemistry and cars maybe give me any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about engines, but from a chemical point of view, the clog that formed in your engine is most likely a hydrated silica. This compound is very insoluble and unreactive - there are only few things that can dissolve silica, e.g., hydrofluoric acid or a hot concentrated solution of sodium/potassium hydroxide, but I wouldn't pour any of these to an engine. Therefore, it seems that your only option is to dismantle the engine and try to remove the clog mechanically.

Comment: Radiator sealants can cause engine damage by clogging the cooling passages in the engine block and cylinder head(s). If you try to use some technique such as forcing water through the block  it's likely some passages will still be left clogged, causing later over-heating and warping of the block. or heads.

Comment: Added sodium hydroxide, aka drain cleaner. Worked well by dissolving the sodium silicate. Thanks though!